# Ruby on Rails application throws an error when I try to deploy it with Heroku. What does this error mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cancancan

I'm using Ruby on Rails to deploy a page. This is my GemFile:

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem 'rails', '~> 7.0.4'

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem 'sprockets-rails'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'

gem 'devise'

gem 'jwt'

gem 'rswag-api'
gem 'rswag-ui'

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem 'importmap-rails'

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem 'turbo-rails'

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem 'stimulus-rails'

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem 'jbuilder'

gem 'cancancan'

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'ffi'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rswag-specs'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem 'web-console'

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end
```

I'm on the main branch and I'm using Heroku to deploy my app.
These were my steps:

```
heroku create
git push heroku main
heroku run rails db:migrate
heroku open
```

When the app opens, I get Application Error, when I run heroku logs in the terminal it says this:

[Here's a link to the error. Stack Overflow won't let me post it here because it looks like spam.](https://justpaste.it/3udya)

This set of steps worked just fine for another RoR app that I made previously. Can someone try to help me decipher this error and see why my app is not running?

Edit: This error seems to be coming from the CanCanCan gem. I still don't know why it is not running

Comment: its pointing at the **cancan** gem, but its not available in the prod gem group...

Comment: so should I move CanCanCan to the general file instead of just the development group?

Comment: well since its your authorization i imagine so. also its the source of your error...

Comment: still doesn't work...

Comment: well I dont know what you did and _still doesn't work..._ doesnt tell me whats not working now. I suggest that you update your question so that it reflects the correct gemfile and the relevant errors

Comment: i moved the cancancan gem to the global Gemfile, ran bundle install, recreated a Heroku app, and ran into the exact same error, which is this one https://justpaste.it/3udya

Comment: does it work in development?

Comment: what do you mean? does what work in development?

Comment: ok so heroku is probably your _production_ environment, while when you boot your rails app locally that would be your _development_ environment (this is when you run ```rails server```). when you run that, do you have the same error? that way at least you can tell if its something happening specifically in _production_ vs something thats already broken in _development_.

Comment: no, i have no issues in development. i was actually able to deploy to heroku when I removed admin privileges in my app. the one thing that never worked was the confirmation email, but that's another issue. thank you